# subset function in r returns o rows with unexplained reason

Tags: r

I have the following kind of dataset.

```
'data.frame':   3204 obs. of  270 variables:
     $ group.investment              : chr  "27four Global Equity Prescient FF A1" "27four Global Equity Prescient FF A2" "27four Global Equity Prescient FF A3" "27four Global Equity Prescient FF A5" ...
     $ ASISA.classification          : chr  " Global EQ General" " Global EQ General" " Global EQ General" " Global EQ General" ...
     $ domicile                      : chr  "South Africa" "South Africa" "South Africa" "South Africa" ..
```

I wanted to subset by $ASISA.classification and have used the following codes alternatively. It returns o rows. I think, i missed something basic may be. Please, needing help.

```
dom.e <- filter(df$ASISA.classification, ASISA.classification == "Global EQ General")
dom.e <- df %>% filter(paste(ASISA.classification == "Global EQ General"))
dom.e <- df[df$ASISA.classification == 'Global EQ General',]
```

Comment: Yes, you missed the leading blank space in `" Global EQ General"`. R did not.

Comment: @LAP Ohh i see. Perfect. This is the answer.